# Any Camera-enabled app will block my Pixel 3 XL camera until reboot

Tags: camera, 9.0-pie, google-pixel-3-xl

I own a Pixel 3 XL phone (Pie). I am experiencing the following:

> When I open **any** camera-enabled app (including Whatsapp and Barcode scanner), the camera subsystem will stop working, the camera-enabled app will crash or just won't show images on screen. After that, the stock Camera app by Google will crash after 10 seconds of attempting to render an image on screen, and the behaviour will persist until reboot

My phone is rooted with Magisk Core, but the framework is stock and is the latest version

I have tried a lot of times to fix issues with caches and user data, but the behaviour is consistent.

- Reset Stock camera to factory version
- Deleted settings and caches from other apps (I didn't reset Whatsapp data, but I tried with Barcode scanner)
- Revoked and reviewed Camera permissions to the very minimum
- Restart in safe mode and in normal mode
- **Haven't yet factory resetted the phone**
- I will probably try to uninstall Magisk and flash the stock boot image

I am very concerned not just because the issue is annoying, but that the camera subsystem is rendered completely unusable until reboot. In Android, apps cannot interfere each other.

I collected a bug report from my phone and sent to my personal email, I am likely to inspect it.

In the meantime, has someone else experienced this problem and found a way to use other camera apps that are not the Stock one?

Comment: Please note: `google-pixel-3-xl` and `crosshatch` tags **are** synonims. I don't know which one is the best to use